# Checking color values without regExp

Tags: javascript

My question might be a little unclear. Same questions were also asked before but I couldn't figure out how to solve mine by reading them. I need more clear guidance:

I have already created three functions to check colors. (I don't have issues with them. I am not including them here because of the size.)
Lets assume we have three working functions like that:

```
function checkHex(input) {
  // returns boolean value if input is hex color
}
checkHex("#1234a6"); // returns true

function checkRGB(input) {
  // returns boolean value if input is RGB color
}
checkRGB("rgb(255, 255, 112)"); // returns true

function checkHSL(input) {
  // returns boolean value if input is hsl color
}
checkHSL("hsl(122, 1, 1)"); // returns true
```

I am having 4th function (checkColor) which has mixed color values to check:

```
function checkColor(input) {
    // returns boolean value if input belong to right color value 
}

checkColor("#ccccff"); // should return true
checkColor("rgb(255,255,200)"); // should return true
checkColor("hls(46,0.66,0.21)"); // should return true
```

QUESTION: Do I have to include all three functions(checkHex,checkRGB,checkHSL) into  the 4th one (checkColor)? How do I do that. I researched about that and tried couple ways to solve but I couldn't.
 I am trying to do it without using RegExp. I am new to programming, never merged multiple functions before. 
Any additional resource you can share with me about "combining multiple functions" will help me a lot too.

Thank you for your time and effort in advance !

Comment: Just do `return checkHex(input) || checkRGB(input) || checkHSL(input);` ?

Comment: See what character/s `input` starts with then call the correct function. Don't forget about `rgba()`.

Answer (score 0):

The first 3 functions you built are often called predicates. There are a bunch of great ways to group predicates but @FelixKling mentions the simplest in the comments. You could also create functions specifically for this purpose.

```js
// composition function
const any = (...predicates) => subject => predicates.reduce((state, predicate) => (state || predicate(subject)), false);

// predicates
const biggerThan5 = x => x>5;
const isOdd = x => !!(x % 2);

// results and usage
console.log(any(biggerThan5, isOdd)(10)); // true
console.log(any(biggerThan5, isOdd)(2)); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't include functions into other functions, you just can use them inside of other ones.
For example:

```
function checkColor(input) {
    var isHex = checkHex(input), //store the result of function
        isRGB = checkRGB(input), //store the result of function
        isHLS = checkHSL(input); //store the result of function
    return isHex || isRGB || isHLS; //returns true if one of the options is true.
}

function checkHex(input) {
  // returns boolean value if input is hex color
}
function checkRGB(input) {
  // returns boolean value if input is RGB color
}
function checkHSL(input) {
  // returns boolean value if input is hsl color
}
```